# Optimizing the given problem to linear time without worrying about space

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures, time-complexity

Given  a list of meeting start time and end time of people's schedules, find the number of people in given time. The time would be given as integers. For example:

Input is

```
[ [ 12, 14] ,[12,15],[14,16],[13,15]]
```

Output should return

```
[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,4,3,1]
```

How to do in linear time?

I can do it in `O(n*m)`.

To find each of the output , scan the input and find the total number of people in given time. That takes `O(n*m)` n = size of input , m = size of output

Comment: It's not clear what *n* is.  If it's supposed to be the size of the input, then you'll take too long for [[1,1000000000]].  If it's supposed to be the size of the output, then you'll take too long for [[1,1],[1,1],[1,1].....]

Comment: n is the size of input

Comment: @user3386109, O(n+m) is the most optimal solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick for doing this in O(n+m) time is:

1. Find the size of the output array required (O(n) time)
2. Allocate the `out` array and fill it with zeros  (O(m) time)
3. For each `[a,b]` in the input, `out[a]+=1; out[b+1]-=1` (O(n) time)
4. Replace each element in the output with the cumulative sum of all elements up to that point.  (O(m) time).  For example `for (int i=1; i<out.length; ++i) out[i]+=out[i-1];`

Comment: can you clarify number 4? especially int i starting from 1

Comment: Line 3 doesn't cover a case when [2,5][3,6] a person is in meeting from 2AM to 5AM and another person 3AM to 6AM. output should return [0,1,2,2,2,1]

Comment: It does.  After 3 you have [0,1,1,0,0,-1,-1...], and then after 4 you have [0,1,2,2,2,1,0...],

Comment: can you clarify number 4 step? especially int i starting from 1

Comment: `out[0]` is left alone.  The `0` from `out[0]` gets added to `out[1]` to make `1`.  The `1` from `out[1]` gets added to `out[2]` to make `2`.  The `2` from `out[2]` gets added to `out[3]` to make `2`... etc. etc.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious algorithm does pretty well:

```
def schedule(spans):
  s = [0] * max(map(max, spans))
  for lo, hi in spans:
    for t in range(lo - 1, hi):
      s[t] += 1
  return s

print str(schedule([[12, 14],[12,15],[14,16],[13,15]]))
```

This is O(L + n) where L is the total length of all the spans and n is the size of the output.

Then:

```
$ python foo.py
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1]
```

Now if you have many overlapping intervals, then you can use a 1d sweep line algorithm to calculate the result on O(n log n + m) time where n is the number intervals and m is the number of output time units.

Something like this, though I won't at all claim this is fully correct:

```
def schedule_faster(spans):
  events = []
  for lo, hi in spans:
    events.append((lo, '+'))
    events.append((hi + 1, '-'))
  events.sort()
  s = [0] * max(map(max, spans))
  n = 0
  t_last = events[0][0]
  for t, dir in events:
    if t != t_last:
      for i in range(t_last - 1, t - 1):
        s[i] = n
      t_last = t
    n += 1 if dir == '+' else -1
  return s
```

Actually if you use a radix sort or other pseudo-linear time sorting algorithm then this becomes O(n + m) in practice.

Comment: what is t_last variable for? Can you explain high level approach of 1d sweep line algorithm  on for t, dir in events: logic inside?